# why three-20 project is creating libThree20.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

Whenever I'm trying to compile a `Three20`- incorporated project in terminal, I'm getting this warning.

```
[exec]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool    : warning for library: /Users/izpulse/IZOHOPULSE_DBUILD/native/ios/Three20/src/Three20/../../Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libThree20.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

Any reasons please...?????